# How circuit is closed again?

Tags: architecture, microservices, hystrix

I am trying to understand Hystrix. I understand when a service makes call to a 3rd party service and that service is not responding and threshold has been exceeded than the configuration, circuit will be opened and onward calls will be short circuited.

But I am not able to understand how circuit is closed again. Let us suppose our service is making call to 3rd party service and that service not not working fine so circuit is opened. After 5 minute that service has started working fine now circuit should be closed. How calling service knows this that the 3rd party service has started behaving fine, now circuited should be closed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are actually three states: OPEN, CLOSED, and HALF_OPEN. Once the circuit breaker is OPEN and a certain amount of time has passed it lets a single request sneak through. This is the HALF_OPEN state. If successful the circuit breaker is closed, otherwise it returns to the OPEN state until that amount of time has passed again, where it enters the HALF_OPEN state once again. You can specify the amount of time between the transition to OPEN to HALF_OPEN using the circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds property.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Hytrix circuit-breaker transition from CLOSED to OPEN. it short-circuits all requests made against that circuit-breaker.

After some amount of time (`HystrixCommandProperties.circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds()`) the next single request is let through 
(this is the HALF-OPEN state).

If the request fails, the circuit-breaker returns to the OPEN state for the duration of the sleep window. 
So, This HALF-OPEN state call determines whether to OPEN or CLOSE circuit.

If the request succeeds, the circuit-breaker transitions to CLOSED and the logic in 1. takes over again. checkout [hystrix working.](https://design.codelytics.io/hystrix/how-it-works)

[image: Circuit Breaker]