# One service is not calling another service after circuit breaker tripped

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is the properties used.

```java
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackFunction", commandProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "2000") }, threadPoolProperties = {
    @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "50"),
    @HystrixProperty(name = "maxQueueSize", value = "100") })
```

circuit breaker tripped due to cloud network latency issue. Once network was restored one service calling to another is unsuccessful, I restarted service one then calling successful.
Can I implement automatic recovery method, so that no need to restart one service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433860/hystrix-how-circuit-is-closed-again

Comment: If circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds property is not set then will circuit breaker come in HALF_OPEN state or not? or can I change state OPEN state to CLOSE state ?

Comment: or If you can add property in my properties and reply with little more  explanation that is great for me.

Comment: You can't change the state, that's the whole point of the circuit breaker. The circuit breaker trips and goes to the open state. Then after a certain time that you specified or the default time of circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds the state will go to half-open. When a request comes through succesfully it goes to open, otherwise it goes to close again.

Comment: If in half-open state and hits the request with result 200-OK then state goes in open or close, as my understanding if in half-open state hit one call to check third party service is running or not, if successfully response the circuit goes in close state otherwise goes again in other state.

Comment: someone answered here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433860/how-circuit-is-closed-again/63534973#63534973)

Comment: someone having more details, please share for more clarity.